# Poor questions quickly upvoted

Tags: discussion

I don't know if anybody else has experienced this but I suspect the use of sock puppets.  Often I come across poor questions such as [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29446875/multiply-percentage-and-variables) which got up-voted in very short order.  Sometimes by the time I look at them they have answers (such as the one in question) but oftentimes they don't, so in the latter case it is not the answer-er doing the up-voting.  I'm guessing SO has some sort of algorithm that detects sock puppets based on IP address, but is there anything else that can be done at a system level in case the IP of the up-voter is different, rather than having to rely on other users down-voting to offset the up-voting?

Comment: Everyone is free to vote as they see fit; there isn't much we can do as this is simply you disagreeing with what makes a question upvote worthy.

Comment: It only got 1 upvote. Hardly something worth worrying about.

Comment: And now due to the meta effect it stands at -3.  I guess for me this is more about being frustrated by seeing 50 poor questions for every good one, and then seeing poor questions up-voted to boot

Comment: Some people seem to  express stupid sentiments with upvotes, for low  (1) rep  users. I'd guess welcoming them or so :( ...

Comment: Yes, it happens.  If you see it "often" then you are probably seeing something else, not sure what.

Comment: I have been noticing single up votes on poor questions within seconds of posting for a while as well...

Comment: A single up-vote might be the result of a (poor) review...